# Reference Requests: Prana-Prathistha in Mahapuranas

Tags: puranas, reference-request

As for now, I'm aware that Prana-Prathistha is a  total tantric concept (dakshinacharya marga) for worshipping deities. There are various sources where prana-prathistha and the manual for the performance of such have been discussed - as such as in various Agamas.

Interestingly, Mahapuranas have rites for various pujas and rituals too and they approve of form and shape-limited worship of deities. So, are there any puranas that actually discuss the **rituals** of prana-prathistha?
Not in the case of big permanent idols (Murti), but even in the case of small temporary stones, images, or rudrakshas (dried seeds of *Elaeocarpus angustifolius*) with proper rituals and mantras?

References from Mahapuranas are welcome the most, not from other samhitas, agamas.

Comment: What you're asking is like asking for details about chemistry to be in a geography book.

Comment: @DushyantShreyaskar Prana Prathistha is usually a very hard rite that cannot be performed with any ordinary ritualist. Whereas, Mahapuranas compiled later on, had a compilation about bhakti, ritual manuals, stories, opinions, etc about a range of things for ordinary, common people. I wanted to know if such manuals for prana prathistha are present in puranas too or not? (In general terms, a miniature version of prana prathistha atleast, not very advanced or fancy one), so that I can grasp the foundational rites of such practices (the ones that forms the base). Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I found so far in the Mahāpurāṇas.

[Shiva Purana chapter 2.1.13 (“The mode of worshipping Śiva”)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc225981.html):

> (36.) The householders shall perform every rite according to prescribed rules. After performing the purificatory rite of the Bhūtas, **the installation of the idol (*prāṇa-pratiṣṭhā*) shall be performed.**
>
> (37-38.) If the worship is performed in the temple of Śiva, the guardians of the quarters shall be installed and worshipped. In the house, Śiva shall be worshipped by the root mantra. It is not obligatory that the gatekeeper shall be worshipped. The liṅga that is worshipped by me can be worshipped in the house. Everything is installed in the same.
>
> (39.) At the time of worship, the lord shall be invoked along with his attendants and paraphernalia. But there is no hard and fast rule governing this aspect.
>
> ...

Also I believe [chapter 2.3.18 of the Bhavishya Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/bhavishya-purana-sanskrit/d/doc1266480.html) is devoted to Prana-Prathistha (Parimal translation). The chapter title is “Consecration rite to be completed in a day”

> Suta said:—During the time of a grave misfortune or distress, there is a provision for the performing of the rites in a single day for the rich people, which I am going to reveal. The concerned person should conclude the adhivasa rites expeditiously. During the Uttarayana (or summer solstice) when the winter season is over and on the arrival of the spring season, the yajna is required to be started. O excellent Brahmanas, in the said yajna, thirty two figures of Narayana and other gods, including those of the goddesses and Ganapati should be worshipped. Then completing the daily routine, the welfare Sraddha should be performed, serving food to a Brahmaņa. Then the intelligent person should enter the place of the yajna. All the deities like Ganesa, besides gods of directions and others should be worshipped at one and the same time and place. Thereafter, the figures of lord Visnu with his family should be lodged over the pedestal. Initially, five types of water, pancamrta, pancagavya and dust of five places should be collected. The gods should be made to take their bath with the same. Then the sesamum oil, fragrant material
> and essence of five types of flowers should be offered. They should be worshipped with Tripatra-Tulasi (holy basil), Kusuma (yellow flower) and the flower petal are called Tripatra. The fruits like pancaka, mango, Acacia, lotus and oleander are known as Pancakas. The elephant tooth (tusk), dust of the hoof of a horse, cow's urine, cowdung. milk, curd and ghi are known as Pancagavya. **Thus completing the consecration (*prana-pratistha*) in an appropriate manner**, the homa should be performed. Thereafter, the final offering should be poured and the daksina should be given.